# Flex Dcm file loading

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, dicom

Working on a project which requires loading dicom files in flex.
Any ideas about loading a DCM(Dicom) file in a flex application

Comment: I have no ideas whatsoever if it is a functional project, but [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dicomflash/) is anyhow a link to a DICOM Flash Viewer from 2007.

Comment: Thanks Anders for a quick reply. Let me go through the files .

Comment: @AndersGustafsson I have downloaded the project and run it. Its loading the DCM file,but the quality is very bad.Trying to fix this issue.Please share if there is any other links

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of [Stratos-viewer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/stratos-viewer/), a Flash based viewer showing Jpeg images obtained from a PACS through WADO. Unfortunately, this project was abandoned about 5 years ago.

After that, I made some tests in flex (actionscript) and I was able to load the raw binary data of an uncomressed Dicom image (Explicit VR, little endian). You can still see a demo [here](http://dicom.netpatia.com/dicom/). The key to be able to do that was the introduction of the [URLLoader class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) in ActionScript. This project was also abandoned (2009) and ended up being just a proof of concept. The good news is that a Dicom file can be loaded (and displayed) in flex.

Now I have abandoned the flash / flex way and I am working on a html5 Dicom viewer, but this is another history.